# Splitting method algorithm

Tags: swift, algorithm, math

`(x^3 - 2x^2 - 5)` is my equation.First of all I have two values like `x = 2 and x = 4.` My first two values must be count for equation and them results must be negative and positive each time. And second step is `(2 + 4) / 2 = 3` this time `x = 3` in equation. And the math operation continue with last one positive value and one negative value. I try this

```
var x = 2.0
var equation = pow(x, 3) - 2 * pow(x, 2) - 5

switch x {
case x : 2
equation = pow(x, 3) - 2 * pow(x, 2) - 5
case x : 4
equation = pow(x, 3) - 2 * pow(x, 2) - 5
default:
0
}  
print(equation)
```

How can I assign first two values like 2 and 4 for one `var x` ?

Comment: So you want to implement the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) to find a solution of the equation x^3-2x^2-5 = 0 ?

Comment: The first step would be to define that equation as a *function:* `func f(x: Double) -> Double { ... }`

Comment: Yes bisection method is look like same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you want to implement the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) to find the (real) solution (“root”) of an equation. The first step is to define that equation as a *function,* so that it can be evaluated at various points:

```
func f(_ x: Double) -> Double {
    return pow(x, 3) - 2 * pow(x, 2) - 5
}
```

Then you need two variables for the left and right boundary of the current interval. These must be chosen such that `f(x)` has opposite signs at the boundaries. In your example:

```
var xleft = 2.0   // f(xleft) < 0
var xright = 4.0  // f(xright) > 0
```

Now you can start the iteration: Compute `f(x)` at the midpoint of the current interval, and replace `xleft` of `xright`, depending on whether `f(x)` is negative or positive. Continue until the approximation is good enough for your purposes:

```
let eps = 0.0000001 // Desired precision
let leftSign = f(xleft).sign

repeat {
    let x = (xleft + xright)/2.0
    let y = f(x)
    if y == 0 {
        xleft = x
        break
    } else if y.sign == leftSign {
        xleft = x
    } else {
        xright = x
    }
    // print(xleft, xright)
} while xright - xleft > eps

// Print approximate solution:
print(xleft)
```

---

The next step would be to implement the bisection method itself as  a function:

```
func bisect(_ f: ((Double) -> Double), xleft: Double, xright: Double, eps: Double = 1.0e-6) -> Double {
    let yleft = f(xleft)
    let yright = f(xright)

    precondition(yleft * yright <= 0, "f must have opposite sign at the boundaries")

    var xleft = xleft
    var xright = xright

    repeat {
        let x = (xleft + xright)/2.0
        let y = f(x)
        if y == 0 {
            return x
        } else if y.sign == yleft.sign {
            xleft = x
        } else {
            xright = x
        }
    } while xright - xleft > eps

    return (xleft + xright)/2.0
}
```

so that it can be used with arbitrary equations:

```
let sol1 = bisect({ x in pow(x, 3) - 2 * pow(x, 2) - 5 }, xleft: 2.0, xright: 4.0)
print(sol1) // 2.690647602081299

let sol2 = bisect({ x in cos(x/2)}, xleft: 3.0, xright: 4.0, eps: 1.0e-15)
print(sol2) // 3.1415926535897936
```